Bibliography style acm.bst - volume's number bold
I am using acm.bst bibliography style. The only change I need is to make bold the volume numbers of Journals.
It seems that the function which takes care of giving the output of the citation style of a journal item is the below function.
Unfortunately I cannot use the solution given in the related question (for unsrt.bst) as this function is very differently defined in unsrt.
FUNCTION {format.journal.vol.num.date}
{ journal empty$
    { "empty journal in " cite$ * warning$
      ""
    }
    { journal
      volume empty$
        'skip$
        { " " * volume * }
      if$
      number empty$
        'emphasizeic
        { emphasize ", " * number * }
      if$
      year empty$
        { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
        { " (" * format.date * ")" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

What I tried:
I replaced emphasize with embolden (and inserting embolden function as in the aforementioned question) without success.

What should happen with the journal field (which comes right before the volume field, separated by a comma)? Should the journal field continue to be rendered in italics (as per the default), or should it be rendered in bold as well? Please advise.

@Mico  The journal title should continue to be rendered in italics (as per the default).
